# how to change the color of row or column in backpack dashboard?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

[This is my client admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFQdV.png)

> What i want to do know when the expire month comes that column will become red automatically otherwise it stay green.

Comment: Can you provide your html and your controller ?

Comment: you have several ways but i need to know you want it in a backend way or frontEnd

Comment: there is no personal blade file for clients sir...

Comment: the most easiest way is to compare the current date to the returned date from your controller , and based on the condition you will set the color of the date

Comment: this is how i am calculating my expire date

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
$month = $request->month;  
$expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths($month);   $request['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;`

Comment: what is the format of $expiry_date? is it dd/mm/yyyy? or what?

Comment: its in  yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: ok i have provided a solution  based on your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view

```
@php
    $currentdate=strtotime(date('Y/m/d'));
    $exp_date=strtotime($expiry_date);

       if($currentdate > $exp_date)
       { //not expired 
         $color="#539E05";
       }
       else
       {
          //expired 
         $color="#EA2C12";
       }
@endphp
  <td style="color: {{$color}}">{{$expiry_date}}</td>
```

i don't know your html structure looks like so i assumed that expiry date exist in span tag

Comment: thnq sir its look good but in backpack there is no blade.php file for my clients table there is only dashboard.blade.php & layout.blade.php

Comment: can you edit your post to provide your controller which set backpack datatable data? so i can edit my answer ?